# Macro in TeXstudio with %<something%> and %(filefilter%) fails

Tags: texstudio

I add the following macro:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=%<0.9%>\columnwidth]{%(*.png, *.pdf%)}
    \caption{%<caption%>}
    \label{fig%<label%>}
\end{figure}
```

TeXstudio inserts the macro on the trigger after asking a file. However, the `0.9` is not marked. Instead the letters `rap` from `includegraphics` are marked. Did I do something wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: Yes, I have. I´m new to TeXstudio and installed it some days ago.

Comment: Hm, now that I play a little bit with it, I get weird results too. Sometimes, `ics` is selected, another time `idt` or even parts of the file name (and always three characters). I guess, there is a bug involved. It seems like spaces in the file names are (at least) one problem.

Comment: Puh! However, when removing the filefilter, even when putting to the next row, everything works fine.

Comment: I think I found the problem. It is dependent of the length of the file name. If I include a file with a name (including the path) of the same length of `*.png, *.pdf` (twelve characters) it works. The more letters, the more the first selection (`0.9`) shifts to the right. There is a (ridiculous) TeX-based work-around, though. (There’s no problem when the file name `%( … %)` comes before the other fields `%< … %>`.)

Comment: However, when switching the optional command with the necessary one, I got an error.

Answer (score 1):

This appear to be a bug in TeXstudio where a file name (including the path) of a different character length as `*.png, *.pdf` (12 characters) throws the selection of the first placeholder `%<0.9%>` off. With exactly 12 characters in the file name it works.

A TeX-based work-around is the following macro making sure that the file name placeholder will be the first thing in the (editor) macro.

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering \def\myFigureNameForTeXstudio{%(*.png, *.pdf%)}
    \includegraphics[width=%<0.9%>\columnwidth]{\myFigureNameForTeXstudio}
    \caption{%<caption%>}
    \label{fig%<label%>}
\end{figure}
```